# How can I get the size of the top-level browsing context’s initial viewport?

Tags: javascript, image, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do image compare and when I capture images with Webdriver their sizes are different from expected because of:

"WebDriver provides the Take Screenshot command to capture the top-level browsing context’s initial viewport" 
"Under the current definitions for taking screenshots (as defined by the open source project), screenshots should be of the full DOM, irrespective of window size."

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1067

I am using:

```
js = 'return Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,  document.documentElement.clientHeight,  document.documentElement.scrollHeight,  document.documentElement.offsetHeight);'
```

to get the total page height with the idea of stitching images together, but this isn't working because of the above.

How do I work with "full DOM" to stitch together a full page image, and for that matter draw element rectangles that are not against window size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [**`WebDriver W3C Candidate Recommendation 30 November 2017`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#take-screenshot) clearly mentions the following :

> **`The Take Screenshot command takes a screenshot of the top-level browsing context’s viewport.`**

Hence it won't be worth to expect a screenshot of the **`Full DOM`** through any of the compatible browser and the implementing methods.

---

I am not sure about any Open Source Specs where it's mentioned as :

> `Under the current definitions for taking screenshots (as defined by the open source project), screenshots should be of the full DOM, irrespective of window size.`

Looking at https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1067 the issue seems just the opposite through **`Protractor`** context where :

```
Resulting image in the case of a width x height = 367 x 667 , was turned into 800x1190
```

Though @JimEvans answer refers :

> **Under the current definitions for taking screenshots (as defined by the open source project), screenshots should be of the full DOM, irrespective of window size. There are two things to note, however. First, Chrome has an outstanding issue where it only creates screenshots of the visible view port. Second, the W3C WebDriver specification defines screenshots as current view port only. No currently shipping driver implementations are spec-compliant yet.**

So we can conclude, until and unless the **`WebDriver`** variants implement the **screenshot of the full DOM** it wouldn't be achievable through the current implemented methods.